# list to check items in checkboxlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a checkboxlist which I have bind with database in which there are around 9000 items , some of them are selected.I have list in which I have 5000 items.I have to check these 5000 items in checkboxlist and remaining unchecked. Please suggest optimized way.

What I try

```
foreach (var eachName in Namelist)
            {
                foreach (ListItem eachCblNameItem in cblName.Items)
                {
                    if (eachCblNameItem.Value == eachName)
                    {
                        eachCblNameItem.Selected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        eachCblNameItem.Selected = false;
                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and hasn't worked.

Comment: Hi @DaveZych I have not said that it does not work ! I have tried with 2 dimensional loop which runs 9000*5000 times.. that is not good I think.

Comment: @DaveZych that is what I have tried

Comment: How did you get your NameList? Maybe you can put it in a HashSet instead of a List and test HashSet.Contains() 9000 times

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea as (linq) pseudo-code:

```
var itemsSelected = from item in checkBoxList.Items
                    join dbItem in database.SelectedItems
                      on item.UniqueKey equals dbItem.UniqueKey
                    select item;

foreach( var item in itemsSelected )
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```